# Space and Newline in Array(Shell script)

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, unix

How to store space and Newline in array. Consider the following is my file.

a.txt:

```
this is file a.txt
for testing
and for checking
```

Now, I want to store each and every character in the file in each element of the array. Like 't' in arr[0], 'h' in arr[1], 'i' in arr[2], 's' in arr[3] and ' '(space) in arr[4] respectively. And If I print the content of array like ${a[*]}, the output is to be exact file content. So, is there any way to store space and newline in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
arr=()

while IFS= read -d '' -r -n1 c; do
    arr+=("$c")
done < file
```

- `read -n1` will make this loop read the input character by character.
- `-d ''` will make delimiter as null instead of newline
- `IFS=` is needed to read leading or trailing spaces in each line.

**Verify:**

```
printf "%s" "${arr[@]}"
this is file a.txt
for testing
and for checking
```

Comment: But Here also the '\n' is not stored in array element

Comment: That's not correct. `\n` is very much part of array `arr`. Check with `declare -p arr` command.